# What does return mean without any datatype?

Tags: java, return

What does `return ;` mean?

As far as I can tell, it means to `return void`.

```
public void method() 
{
    System.out.println("here2");
    return ;
}
```

Can anybody please explain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means to return nothing - `void` to be specific. Used to return out of method. It is used with method with return type `void` , if you want to return early from the method based on some condition like:

```
public void method(int parameter)
{
  if(parameter < 0)
     return;
  //otherwise continue with the following. 
  System.out.println("here2");
}
```

In your current code, you are not required to write `return` since the method will return normally from the last line of code.

[Returning a Value from a Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

> Any method declared void doesn't return a value. It does not need to
>   contain a return statement, but it may do so. In such a case, **a
>   return statement can be used to branch out of a control flow block and
>   exit the method**

Comment: well , i just made a demo method to question the concept , its not like I need it , i also knew the same thing , but some unhealthy discussion led me to a confusion , so i asked , thanks for the clearance and that in a better way

Comment: @Habib : my actual doubt comes from here , can you please take a look ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195578/how-to-explain-return-statement-within-constructor

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid, seems you already got answers for the question, in constructor return would mean to return out of the current control flow. It still returns `nothing` - `void`, it is just moving out of the control flow.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid, plus you may see this discussion http://www.coderanch.com/t/532936/java/java/return-statement-valid-java-constructor

Answer (score 0):

We are  simply just  returning the **CONTROL** to the calling function.