# Returning from a constructor causes a compile error on lambda parameters: "error: variable might not have been initialized"

Tags: java

When compiling a class that contains a return statement in its constructor, and a member variable whose constructor takes a lambda with parameters, I get a compile error.

Example code:

```java
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class App {

    final Timer timer = new Timer(1_000, e -> {});

    public App() {
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("TIMER IS " + new App().timer);
    }

}
```

Running `javac App.java` (with Oracle JDK 1.8.0_191) results in:

```
App.java:8: error: variable e might not have been initialized
        return;
        ^
1 error
```

Take out the return statement in the constructor, and it compiles. Convert the lambda to an anonymous class, and it also compiles.

What's even stranger: IDEs seem to be okay with it. The above code can actually be run in VS Code, and none of Eclipse, NetBeans, and IntelliJ show up any errors. The only reason it came up for me was that my Gradle build was failing.

What's going on here, am I missing something?

Comment: **Why are you putting a return statement in a constructor??**

Comment: @Makoto technically, that's not the problem. It's conceivable to have a loop or something in a constructor.

Comment: @kumesana:  It's a very, very strong code smell to me.  [I know that it's possible to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15195610/1079354), and I know that there are some valid reasons to do this, but that doesn't mean that it's just "okay" to do.  In this context, the OP has no valid reason to *want* this behavior, and therefore I would see that as the problem.

Comment: @Makoto It smells yes, but I'd say that the idea that the language doesn't compile what it's supposed to compile, is a valid complaint. And code smells don't justify not compiling

Comment: Sure.  Fair enough.  In either event, it'd be fixed in Java 9.

Comment: My apologies, I was so sure that I had searched hard enough for that one. Thanks for the quick response!

As for why I'm doing it...um...I'll just lay the blame on legacy code...